# Pip install a package's dependencies only, but not the package itself

Tags: python, pip, dependencies

This question may appear to have been answered in the past, however, all answers are out-of-date and do not work.

Flags like `pip install --deps-only xyz` appears a lot in searches, however a PR for the feature was closed without being merged.

I am trying to automate a pre-build of a Docker image with all dependencies pre-installed for a package `xyz`, *however*, I do not want the package `xyz` installed at this stage. The package gets installed on the image at later stages as it changes a lot (including the data that comes with the package). As you may have guessed, a private pypi repository is used.

An example:

A package `xyz` has dependencies `a, b, c`. I only want `a, b, c` installed, but not  the `xyz` package.

Ideally, I do not want to install additional libraries to accomplish this.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: is it a .tar.gz or is it a whl file?

Comment: It's a whl file

Comment: This question was asked many times before and the answer remains the same - there is currently no way without explicitly downloading the wheel and extracting metadata.

Comment: @Sazzy What if there is no way to install dependencies but not the main package? What's wrong with installing it? You can install it, uninstall and reinstall at will. Or install and later upgrade. Why not?

Comment: @phd that is how I currently have it implemented, however, it's definitely not ideal.

Answer (score -2):

You can download the source file on pypi and find a file called requirements.txt extract it and do

```
pip install -R requirements.txt
```

You can try instailig the package an the removing it with

```
pip install [package name]
pip unistall [package name]
```

Comment: It's a wheel package, it does not contain a requirements.txt file.